# Database record not being created, maybe issue with relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and am trying to create a new database record.  I had this working, until I started involving relationships.

What I have is:
A users table that has_many shops and has_many shops_datum
A Shops table that belongs_to users and has_many shops
A Shops_datum tabel that belongs_to users and belongs_to shops

Here is my code for each of these models:

Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :shop_datum
  has_many :shops
end
```

Shop Model:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :shop_datum
    belongs_to :user
end
```

ShopData Model:

```
class ShopDatum < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shop
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the db schema for these three:

```
create_table "shop_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "data_title"
    t.integer "jan_data"
    t.integer "feb_data"
    t.integer "mar_data"
    t.integer "apr_data"
    t.integer "may_data"
    t.integer "jun_data"
    t.integer "jul_data"
    t.integer "aug_data"
    t.integer "sep_data"
    t.integer "oct_data"
    t.integer "nov_data"
    t.integer "dec_data"
    t.integer "ytd_data"
    t.integer "other_data"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "shop_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["shop_id"], name: "index_shop_data_on_shop_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_shop_data_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "shop_name"
    t.string "owner_name"
    t.string "email_address"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_shops_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "shop_data", "shops"
  add_foreign_key "shop_data", "users"
  add_foreign_key "shops", "users"
```

And then, I have a controller that is searching for a record in the ShopData table, and either creating or updating records based on what it finds.  Here is that model's code:

```
class AccessEmailController < ApplicationController
    require 'roo'
    def access_email

        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])
        service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
        service.authorization = client

        user_id = 'me'

        email_list = service.list_user_messages('me', q: "subject:(CCC Data)")
        
        message = 'No Emails Found' if email_list.messages.empty?
       
        email_list.messages.each do |msg|
            message = service.get_user_message(user_id, msg.id)
            parts = message.payload.parts || []
            parts.each do |part|
                @attachment_id = part.body.attachment_id
            end

            attachment = service.get_user_message_attachment(user_id, msg.id, @attachment_id)
  
            File.open("./attachment_data.xlsx", "wb") { |f| f.write attachment.data }

            xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(File.expand_path('./attachment_data.xlsx'))
            xlsx.default_sheet = xlsx.sheets.first
            header = xlsx.first_row
            @shopTitle = xlsx.row(1)[0]

            xlsx.drop(header).each do |row|
                if ShopDatum.where(data_title: row[0], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: @shopTitle).exists?
                   shopData = ShopDatum.find_by(data_title: row[0], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: @shopTitle)
                   shopData.update(data_title: row[0], jan_data: row[2], feb_data: row[3], mar_data: row[4], apr_data: row[5], may_data: row[6], jun_data: row[7], jul_data: row[8], aug_data: row[9], sep_data: row[10], oct_data: row[11], nov_data: row[12], dec_data: row[13], ytd_data: row[14], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: 5)
                else
                    ShopDatum.create(data_title: row[0], jan_data: row[2], feb_data: row[3], mar_data: row[4], apr_data: row[5], may_data: row[6], jun_data: row[7], jul_data: row[8], aug_data: row[9], sep_data: row[10], oct_data: row[11], nov_data: row[12], dec_data: row[13], ytd_data: row[14], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: 5)
                end
            end
            #Autobodyshop.create(month: xlsx.cell('D', 1), category: "Test data", total: 500)

        end
    end
end
```

When I run the access_email action, though, the console is showing a lot of select queries, one for each row in the excel sheet, but is not showing any create queries.  And then, when I query the database, it has no data in the shopdata table.

Here is the console output:

```
 ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Sales Collision ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Repair Orders (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Sales P&M ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Purchases P&M ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Sales Parts ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Purchases Parts ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Sales Paint Labor ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Hours Paint Labor Sold (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Sales Body Labor ($)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Hours Body Labor Sold (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" IS NULL AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $1 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Productive Square Foot (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Total Square Foot (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Booths (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Repair Planning Stalls (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (4.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Body Stalls (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Frame Stalls (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Paint Stalls (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Detail Stalls (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Total Number of Stalls"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Body Techs (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Paint Techs (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Total Number of Productive Employees"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Estimators (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Repair Planners (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Number of Other Overhead Staff (#)"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Total Number of Non-Productive Employees"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  ShopDatum Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_data" WHERE "shop_data"."data_title" = $1 AND "shop_data"."user_id" = $2 AND "shop_data"."shop_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["data_title", "Total Number of Staff"], ["user_id", 1], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/access_email_controller.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in access_email'
  Rendering access_email/access_email.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered access_email/access_email.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 1451ms (Views: 135.4ms | ActiveRecord: 86.0ms | Allocations: 288649)
```

I suspect that the issue is that I am doing something wrong with the relationships, but am a bit stuck on how to move forward.  Does anyone have any thoughts on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

i think all your @shopTitle value is null, maybe that cause the problem.

The model i think it based on your business, but if you want to get shop data by user you can do this also

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shops
  has_many :shop_datum, through: :shops
end
```

```ruby
      xlsx.drop(header).each do |row|
       shopData = current_user.shop_datum.where(shop_id: @shopTitle, data_title: row[0]).first
                if shopData.present?
                   shopData.update(data_title: row[0], jan_data: row[2], feb_data: row[3], mar_data: row[4], apr_data: row[5], may_data: row[6], jun_data: row[7], jul_data: row[8], aug_data: row[9], sep_data: row[10], oct_data: row[11], nov_data: row[12], dec_data: row[13], ytd_data: row[14], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: 5)
                else
                    ShopDatum.create(data_title: row[0], jan_data: row[2], feb_data: row[3], mar_data: row[4], apr_data: row[5], may_data: row[6], jun_data: row[7], jul_data: row[8], aug_data: row[9], sep_data: row[10], oct_data: row[11], nov_data: row[12], dec_data: row[13], ytd_data: row[14], user_id: current_user.id, shop_id: 5)
                end
            end
```